# German special character displayed wrong on Firefox

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, firefox, utf-8

I have a list with German text that includes special characters like *Ä*, *Ö*, etc.

I develop my website using chrome, which takes care of these characters automatically, but some of them can't be displayed in the FireFox browser.

After trying to use  `mb_convert_encoding( STRING, 'utf-16', 'utf-8' )` to encode my string, it works well in FireFox, but not in Chrome anymore (The characters are displayed like this: �). I already used `charset="UTF-8"` in my `<meta>`tag.

Is there a way to fix this for both browsers?

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you try to convert using [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)?

Comment: @chade_ i tried using iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", STRING) and its just like when i use mb_convert_encoding( STRING, 'utf-16', 'utf-8' )

Comment: What encoding is the text actually in, what encoding is declared in the meta tags (UTF-8, yes?), what encoding is declared in the HTTP headers?

Comment: @deceze yes, encoding that i use for meta tags is UTF-8, and for HTTP headers, it is ISO-8859-1

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Fix your headers.

Comment: @deceze i tried it and its works, Thanks !! :)

Comment: @deceze just want to confirm, before i change my response header to UTF-8, it's works well in Chrome, is this mean Chrome has some feature to handle this?

Comment: Maybe it's trying to iron out your mistakes, like when there's a discrepancy between HTTP headers and meta tags it tries to figure out which seems more likely. I don't know, it's up to each browser to handle that as best it can. It's *your* job to set the correct headers.

Comment: @deceze okay, thank you for your explanation. please submit your answer so i can close this :)